# Google's Provided Code Example "Fails to load resource" (500 Error)

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I almost perfectly mimicked the code example on Google's documentation pages, but the share api still fails.

The documentation pages I read from are:

- [Building a Collaborative App in Drive](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/realtime-quickstart#step_2_set_up_the_sample)
- [Launching the Google Drive sharing dialog in your app](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing#launching_the_google_drive_sharing_dialog_in_your_app)

Putting them together, I get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Google Realtime Quickstart</title>
    <!-- Load Styles -->
    <link href="https://www.gstatic.com/realtime/quickstart-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Load the Realtime JavaScript library -->
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
    <!-- Load the utility library -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/realtime/realtime-client-utils.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="background-color:red" onclick="s.showSettingsDialog()">Share</div>
    <main>
        <h1>Realtime Collaboration Quickstart</h1>
        <p>Now that your application is running, simply type in either text box and see your changes instantly appear in the other one. Open this same document in a <a onclick="window.open(window.location.href);return false;" target="_blank">new tab</a> to see it work across tabs.</p>
        <textarea id="text_area_1"></textarea>
        <textarea id="text_area_2"></textarea>
        <button id="auth_button">Authorize</button>
    </main>
    <script>
        var clientId = 'xx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
        if (!/^([0-9])$/.test(clientId[0])) {
            alert('Invalid Client ID - did you forget to insert your application Client ID?');
        }
        // Create a new instance of the realtime utility with your client ID.
        var realtimeUtils = new utils.RealtimeUtils({
            clientId: clientId
        });
        authorize();

        function authorize() {
            // Attempt to authorize
            realtimeUtils.authorize(function(response) {
                if (response.error) {
                    // Authorization failed because this is the first time the user has used your application,
                    // show the authorize button to prompt them to authorize manually.
                    var button = document.getElementById('auth_button');
                    button.classList.add('visible');
                    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
                        realtimeUtils.authorize(function(response) {
                            start();
                        }, true);
                    });
                } else {
                    start();
                }
            }, false);
        }

        function start() {
            // With auth taken care of, load a file, or create one if there
            // is not an id in the URL.
            var id = realtimeUtils.getParam('id');
            if (id) {
                // Load the document id from the URL
                realtimeUtils.load(id.replace('/', ''), onFileLoaded, onFileInitialize);
            } else {
                // Create a new document, add it to the URL
                realtimeUtils.createRealtimeFile('New Quickstart File', function(createResponse) {
                    window.history.pushState(null, null, '?id=' + createResponse.id);
                    realtimeUtils.load(createResponse.id, onFileLoaded, onFileInitialize);
                });
            }
        }
        // The first time a file is opened, it must be initialized with the
        // document structure. This function will add a collaborative string
        // to our model at the root.
        function onFileInitialize(model) {
            var string = model.createString();
            string.setText('Welcome to the Quickstart App!');
            model.getRoot().set('demo_string', string);
        }
        // After a file has been initialized and loaded, we can access the
        // document. We will wire up the data model to the UI.
        function onFileLoaded(doc) {
            var collaborativeString = doc.getModel().getRoot().get('demo_string');
            wireTextBoxes(collaborativeString);
        }
        // Connects the text boxes to the collaborative string
        function wireTextBoxes(collaborativeString) {
            var textArea1 = document.getElementById('text_area_1');
            var textArea2 = document.getElementById('text_area_2');
            gapi.drive.realtime.databinding.bindString(collaborativeString, textArea1);
            gapi.drive.realtime.databinding.bindString(collaborativeString, textArea2);
        }
        init = function() {
            s = new gapi.drive.share.ShareClient();
            //s.setOAuthToken(clientId);
            s.setOAuthToken(gapi.auth.getToken());
            s.setItemIds([realtimeUtils.getParam('id').replace('/','')]);
        }
        window.onload = function() {
            gapi.load('drive-share', init);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The result is this:

```
GET https://drive.google.com/sharing/share?id=xxxx_xxxxxxxx&fore…
d=false&client=postMessage&embedOrigin=www.example.com 500 ()
    _.k.$l @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:651
    _.k.S @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:651
    _.k.Ql @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:794
    ys.kc @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:791
    Ts.OV @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:822
    Zs @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:814
    FM @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:818
    Ts.Ph @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:818
    pt.Na @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:829
    onclick @ ?id=xxxx_xxxxxxxx:15
```

The only part I modified was adding the red div at the top with the on-click event. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 1**
I found one problem with the above: I was passing in clientId instead of the oauth token (in the init function). However, fixing this did not change anything, not even any of the lines of the reported error.

**Edit 2**
The error occurs when I click the red div element that says 'share'. Forgot to say that.

Comment: Tried out your code above. Just replaced the clientId with mine. Works fine. No error of any sort. [Error 500](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.6.1) is an Internal Server Error. Are you sure there's nothing disrupting in your connections? Cheers!

Comment: Are you saying the google drive api showed up for you? That is exciting to hear! The code still fails on my end, so I am curious about more information from you. Were you running on localhost? Python http server? What browser were you using? If I can duplicate your success, that would allow me to figure out what happened with mine.   **Oh, and thank you for trying and commenting on this!**

Comment: Also, what operating system?

Comment: Also which apis did you enable on console.developers.google.com? Thanks again, and sorry for so many questions.

Comment: No worries. My OS is Ubuntu. Chrome browser. Used python. I just followed exactly what was in the quickstart link you provided.

Comment: Huh. Okay, that is very interesting. Perhaps it is as you suggested, as I am running near exactly the same software as you. I guess I shall try it on another network. Would that answer your first "Are you sure there's nothing disrupting in your connections?" question, or did you mean something else?

Comment: Yep. Do try it on a different connection. Let me know how it goes. Cheers!. :)

Comment: Okay, dumb question, I realized I forgot to say when the error happened. Can you bring up the share dialogue? (by pressing the 'share' div)

Comment: Sorry, mate. Nothing is happening when I click on the div.

Comment: Sigh. Then I honestly have no idea what is going on. Well, thank you for the help you did give!